# How to debug/diagnose cause of Powershell Copy-Item command failing in psake script?

Tags: powershell, psake

I have a very simple script that uses Copy-Item in the Task Build section following the **[psake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psake)** conventions (and examples). Right now that's all it does in an attempt to simplify the script to debug this issue.

**The Error:**

> 18/07/2011 5:40:57 PM: An Error Occurred:
>
> Exec: Error executing command:  Copy-Item "$src_dir..\somefolder*.dll" $bin_dir

I have tried just outputting the file paths via Write-Host and they look fine.

I need some help please debugging this, getting the script code (Copy-Item) to work in isolation to **psake** isn't an objective.

**The Script:**

```
Properties {
    $src_dir = Split-Path $psake.build_script_file
    $bin_dir= "$build_dir\..\Binaries\"
}

include .\psake_ext.ps1

Task Build -Depends Clean, Init {
    Write-Host "about to error here:"

    Exec { Copy-Item "$src_dir\..\somefolder\*.dll" $bin_dir }

    Write-Host "do NOT get this far"
    #more similar Exec copy commands, that don't execute
}

Task Clean {    

}
```

**Also note:**

> This script was working and only intermittently failing in the very recent past, 
>   but now seems to fail more consistently.

**Executed via:**

```
.\psake.ps1 "failing-copy-script.ps1" Build
```

Comment: Why is this question closed?? Voted for reopening..

Comment: I don't use PSake, but I would bet that it isn't blocking errors from being stored in $Error.

Comment: The error was something strange happening with locking of files, something external to the script. It would always be solved by closing a few applications / system restart, so I flagged the question for closing myself. Did not think "have you tried turning it off and on again" was a good answer.

Comment: Part of the problem was using 'Exec { Copy-Item }' -- advice is don't. Just call 'Copy-Item'

Comment: @Dori♦ @Dori - Why was this closed??

Comment: @manojlds - read what it says under the close reason, below.

Comment: @Dori♦ @Dori - yeah, yeah, but I am saying that is not the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this question has an answer, summarizing the comments from question and other info:

If you are experiencing this issue diagnostic steps to take:

1. "Have you tried turning it off and on again?" - Close anything that may have to do with the script, including your IDE, even restart your machine.
2. Try a tool like [lockhunter](http://lockhunter.com/download.htm)
3. Avoid using 'Exec { bla }' command if it is not required.
4. Search for hooks with [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653)